# No Record Found message in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Here is my code, question is where and how should I code for showing the No record Found when there is no result found in the database?

```
Dim sql = "SELECT Schedule FROM tblTeacherInfo WHERE Schedule = '" & lbl_Date.Text & "'"
lbl_Date.Text = Date.Today

con = connectDB()

con.Open()

mycommand = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader

If dr.Read Then
Dim mydate As DateTime = mydate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

If txtReceived.TextLength < 8 Then
lbl_Full.Text = "No Record Found"
con.Close()
Else
con.Close()
con.Open()
MsgBox("Data Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "String Size Specification")

mycommand = New SqlCommand("update tblTeacherInfo set Schedule = '" & lbl_Date.Text & "' where PatronID = @patronid", con)
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patronid", txtReceived.Text)
mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
txtReceived.Clear()
lbl_Department.Text = ""
lbl_Full.Text = " "
End If
```

This is a tap card system. if i tap the card and not yet in the database, it will prompt the user using textbox that the record is not yet existing. How and where should i code that? thank you. Edit: I already tried using IsDBNull, dt.Rows.Count = 0. but its not working too. or maybe i just dont know where and how to put them here :D so i need your advise thanks a lot

Comment: `If dr.Read Then` => you should use `If dr.HasRows Then` instead. Seems that you're not pulling anything from `SELECT` query.

Comment: You code has serious sql-injection vulnerability, always use parameterized queries!

Comment: i cant get it, dr.HasRows not working for me.

and yes i will Sir Esko. sorry bout that

Comment: "dr.HasRows not working"...what do you mean? What value does it return? If it returns false, then your query returned no results. If it returns true, then your query returned some rows and you should be able to read them